# How to access a child of an object in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Let's say I have created an object which can have children and have `getChildren()` method, f.e. `Group()`. Then I created an another object which can 'store' children, too, f.e. `VBox()`. And then again I create yet an another object, f.e. `Slider()`.

So now I add the Slider object to the list of VBox children by calling `myVBox.getChildren().add(mySlider);`, and then I add the VBox object to the list of Group object. Supose that everything is performed inside a function that returns `myGroup` object.

Now I'm outside of the function, I have no direct way to access Slider properties, I need to access Group children, get the VBox, then get the Slider from VBox children.

So as far as I understand, I should call `myGroup.getChildren().get(0);` to get the first child added (which in this case should be the VBox object). Now I need to go deeper, so I should call `myGroup.getChildren().get(0).getChildren().get(0);`, right?

Unfortunately the object returned by `myGroup.getChildren().get(0);` does not have a `getChildren()` method and it's type of Node class, while `myGroup.getChildren().get(0).getClass();` returns info that that child is type of VBox.

I'm quite a freshmen in Java, so please, so please, point out my misconceptions.

Comment: You could just make them instance variables (i.e. declare them at the class level) instead of local variables in the method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Slider` inside a `VBox` with other nodes, and this box is inside a group, you can access the inner slider with `getChildren()` by casting the resulting node to its type. And before that, make sure you can do this casting by cheking if the node is instance of the specific class with `instanceof`.

This simple example will help you.

```
private final Group group = new Group();
private final VBox vbox = new VBox();
private final Button button = new Button("Click");
private final Label label = new Label("Slider Value: ");

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(button, label, new Slider(0,10,4));
    vbox.setSpacing(20);
    group.getChildren().add(vbox);

    button.setOnAction(e->{
        Node nodeOut = group.getChildren().get(0);
        if(nodeOut instanceof VBox){
            for(Node nodeIn:((VBox)nodeOut).getChildren()){
                if(nodeIn instanceof Slider){
                    label.setText("Slider value: "+((Slider)nodeIn).getValue());
                }
            }

        }      
    });
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's now working flawlessly. I have only an additional little question - why is it required to cast the resulting node to it's type? What are pros of this mechanics in Java?

Comment: The reason is `getChildren` doesn't know about the type of its children, and returns the base class. You can read about that in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) or on any tutorial. And if the answer was valid, please accept it.

Comment: @JoséPereda What does `get(0)` means? I know that you're searching for the group children, but I don't understand the "0". It's supposed to be the index, but the only thing that has indexes (according to SceneBuilder at least) it's a GridPane. And even int hat case, it has 2 indexes (rows and columns).

Comment: `getChildren` returns an observable list of nodes. As any list, you can get any of its items by their index. `get(0)` will return the first item in the list, in the example it will be the `VBox` instance `vbox`, which was the only node added to the group.